# While running the MVC4 unit test case in VS 2012 getting error An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v1':

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

While trying to run my unit test cases in MVC4 in VS 2012, I am getting Error:-

An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v1': Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I searched a lot and most of answer is for Entity framework dll but I am not using Entity Framework .

I created the unit test cases in MVc3 and recently, we converted to MVC4. but I am not sure it is because of the same as other folks in my team are able to run their test cases.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just wright following method in your test mentod's class.

```
    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        //Clear you object here. whatever in error message.
        OperationContext.OperationContext.Clear();
    }
```

I was also facing this kind of issue, after adding this function, It will work.

Comment: Thanks Gurpreet for the reply. one quick question - Do I need to add OperationContext also?? it seems to be present in System.ServiceModel namespace which is related to WCF.